# Page content wont change on back button press

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag with a button in it:

```
    <div class="mb-5 mt-5">
        <a href="/examplepath">
            <button class="btn-lg font-size-15 btn-round btn-dark b-0" style="width: 100%;background: linear-gradient(to top right, #ff9933 0%, #ff33cc 80%);cursor: pointer;">Watch the free training</button>
        </a> 
    </div>
```

When i click this button it takes me to a path on my site `/examplepath`

When i am in `/examplepath` and i press on the back button of my browser, the content doesn't change.

The URL changes, the title of the site changes, and if i inspect the code, the code changes too. The only thing that doesn't change is the actual content i am viewing.

Not sure what can cause this, any ideas?

Comment: Is your site hosted online or local?

Comment: @Anthony it's happening both online, and in local host

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of the webpage and the debugger you're using which shows the different code.  The fundamental job of a browser is the render and display the code.

Comment: Does the link point to a "section" of the page or a completely new page?

Comment: @Anthony , i put the entire URL instead of just the path like you said and it worked, go ahead and repost your answer so i can accept it thanks.

Comment: @RickS awesome! glad i could help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute path if the website is online! Sometimes relative paths can cause issues.